# CSS Background image with pattern overlay effect issue

Tags: html, css

This is the background image that I want to show as the full body background. The background has a 'pattern overlay' effect in Adobe Photoshop. I cannot get the background to look properly(the spaces between the pattern is less in my background).

This is the image of the background.

http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/7622/backgroundfz.png

My attempt at this can be found at http://www.sarahjanetrading.com/js/j/index.html

I would really appreciate the help

Thanks

Comment: Can we see your existing CSS?

Comment: @Whetstone * {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
body {
 background: url(images/body-bg.png) repeat;
}

Comment: Please share the code so that we can help out easily.

Comment: @Aniket What code? it is one line of CSS that is clearly visible in the browser

Comment: @Aniket Your example looks fine in my browser.  Follow Grega's advice and it should on yourse as well, I think you're just zoomed out!

Comment: Thanks guys. I guess its just me who thought they look different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is exported as a .png, so the image itself is good. My guess is, that you have zoomed out with your browser. Try using a different browser, or change your zoom to 100%.